# Height in IE is displaying diffrent to firefox

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox, height

I have a problem with displaying a set height in ie.

In my css I have set a height for my sidebar div as 2150px; which it displays fine in firefox but does not display the full height in ie.

How can I get ie to display the height I have set in ie?

Thanks in advance

The source code is below

```
#sidebar_newspr{
width:160px;
min-height:2150px; 
margin-top:1px; margin-right:2px;
border-right-style:solid; border-right-color:#900; border-right-width:1px;
float:left;
}
 #sidebar_newspr a{
 text-decoration:none;
 color:#FFF;
 font-size:12px; font-family:Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
 }
 #sidebar_newspr a:hover{
 color:#900;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit of a shot in the dark because you didn't really specify which versions of IE you're testing it in.  Nevertheless, `min-height` requires IE7 and IE8 to be operating in Standards Mode.  To enable Standards Mode, you need to use a strict `!DOCTYPE`.

From [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms530815(VS.85).aspx):

> In **Internet Explorer 7**, the min-height/max-height attributes apply to floating and absolutely positioned block, inline-block elements, and some intrinsic controls. They do not apply to non-replaced inline elements, such as table columns and row/column groups. (A "replaced" element has intrinsic dimensions, such as an img or textArea.)
>
> In **Internet Explorer 7**, this property is enabled only under the strict !DOCTYPE.

`min-height` in IE6 applies only to `th`, `td` and `tr` elements.

Comment: In IE6 height acts like min-height.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use conditional comments:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]> //will target IE less than version 9
        <link href="/directroy/IE.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<![endif]-->
```

To your head tag and use this new stylesheet to define what you want IE to do.

```
#sidebar_newspr{
width:160px;
height:2150px; /*change to just height*/
margin-top:1px; margin-right:2px;
border-right-style:solid; border-right-color:#900; border-right-width:1px;
float:left;
}
```

You can also use more than one Conditional comments to target different versions of IE.

Like so:

```
<!--[if IE 8]> //will target only IE 8
        <link href="/directroy/IE.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<![endif]-->
```

Then try to set your doctype to strict:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"

"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

Might work, if not then I'm sure someone else has another idea :)

Answer (score 0):

Some versions of IE dislike `min-height`, I try to tend to avoid it if possible.

As a quick solution that wont weigh your page down like an IE only style, simply state `height:2150px; min-height:2150px;` Browsers that support `min-height` will take that, while the ones that don't support it will simply ignore it.